# ADSL router not working with Ubuntu Server 16.04.1 LTS

Tags: server, router, adsl

The same ADSL router (Huawei HG633) works fine for my Ubuntu desktop when connected over wifi, but when I try doing "sudo apt update" on a newly-installed Ubuntu Server 16.04.1 it doesn't detect the internet. I am connected to the router using an Ethernet cable.

Is this a known issue with Ubuntu Server and ADSL routers?

Edit: (sorry to post a screenshot but I couldn't get anything off of this machine another way)
[image]

Comment: Will do, though I am not in front of the machine presently. I remember being surprised that I only noticed a ipv6 address there but this was last night (so I might have not remembered that correctly).

Comment: Well, when you can, please add that information. Right now, there's not really enough information to determine if it's an issue with your router configuration/compatibility or your client-side configuration/setup.

Comment: Added the output of ifconfig

Comment: The image you linked is not the full output of the `ifconfig` command. Please take another picture from further back to include all of the output for us to help you.

Comment: The only bits that got chopped off said "frame:0" and "carrier: 0". The gist is that there is no IP address being given by the router for some reason, though I am also inquiring with the ISP who supplied it.